# BlockSize and big data

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Everyone knows that Hadoop have a poor handling of small files cause of the number of the mappers that it have to use.
but what about large files which is little bit bigger than the block size.

as an example, let's say that the hdfs block size is 128mb and that hadoop receives files between 126mb and 130mb.

the files between 126mb and 128mb will be suitable for storage in hadoop but what about the 129mb-130mb ones , do hadoop need 2 mappers in order to read those files ? how to handle this problem in hadoop betside the fact of making hdfs blocks bigger ?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of mappers depends on the number of input splits calculated by the framework, and not that of the blocks that constitute a file. An input split can exceed a block. In that case, that data which exceeds the size of the block will still be processed by a single map task. Input split is the logical unit of computation (by mappers) whereas a block is the logical unit of storage(by HDFS).

That said, a second mapper would be required if the file has a second input split.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer it answers my question, do you have any article that explains how the size and number of input splits are choosen and what is the relation between those splits and the hdfs blocks ( beside the data )?

Comment: Please take a look at 'Hadoop: The definitive giude by Tom White'. It is a slow read book. You will appreciate the details over there.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! i'll do it :) but at short term i need a quick answer for one of my customers, so if you have any good article dont hesitate :) thanks a lot.

Comment: Otherwise i do not agree that blocks are logical layer, rather they are physical ones, i can agree that HDFS blocks are logical if we were talking about the abstraction on top of OS level.

Answer (score 1):

Once you cross the 128Mb boundry, you need a second block.

for example the file 130mb will be displayed as 2 Blocks : the first 128 and the second the rest of the file

HDFS is meant to handle large files. Lets say you have a 1000Mb file. With a 4k block size, you'd have to make 256,000 requests to get that file (1 request per block). In HDFS, those requests go across a network and come with a lot of overhead. Each request has to be processed by the Name Node to figure out where that block can be found. That's a lot of traffic! If you use 64Mb blocks, the number of requests goes down to 16, greatly reducing the cost of overhead and load on the Name Node.

Comment: i agree, thanks for your answer ! actually i think i wasn't clear.

my question is to know if hadoop will use 2 mappers for the 129mb and 130mb files, and if it's the case what are the other solutions beside making the hdfs block bigger ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misconception about the relationship between HDFS and mapreduce.  HDFS is the underlying file system, mapreduce is the compute framework.  HDFS on it's own does not use the mapreduce framework at all for it's operation.  Mapreduce jobs use HDFS as the file system when looking for it's job jars, to write temporary processing data, to pull files to process or any other file operation.  The number of mappers/reducers are set at job submission time and is up to the mapreduce client submitting the job.

If you have a 500MB file that has been split into 4 blocks of 128MB and you want to run a word count mapreduce job that reads a file and outputs the count of each occurring word, and you run it with 4 mappers and 2 reducers, you will end up with each map task processing one of the 4 x 128MB blocks.  The job will talk to the HDFS namenode to request the file, the namenode will respond with all the blocks required to build the file and also give the location of the blocks.  The map phase will read those files from their datanodes and produce 4 files after processing them (e.g. part-0000, part-0001,part-0002, part-0003), the reduce phase will sort and tally up the words in each file and give it's final output.

**You don't need to make the blocks bigger just because your file is larger than the block size**. That defeats the purpose of a distributed file system or any file system in existence. HDFS (and all file systems I've used) can have an 8GB file - it will still break it up into 128MB chunks or whatever you set as your block size.

Comment: Thanks for your answer OkezieE,
yes, my message was confusing cause i used hdfs instead of Hadoop.

otherwise : 
--> i'm agree that with a 8Gb files there is no need to resize the block size cause  hadoop will have a good blocks splitting overall value - it will maybe have 1/64 chance to have a smallfile -  but when your are using files with a size between 128mb and 130mb you'l have a 50% chance to have small files.

--> according to mapredcuce, if i understood, you mean that the number of map & reduce and defined when creating the M/R job ? if so, how things happen in hive ? is it automact